# scala - play json JsValue conver to generic type

Tags: scala

I tried to extract map data from json.

```
def getMap[K, V](js: JsValue, key: String): Map[K, V] = {
        js \ key match {
            case JsDefined(v) => v.as[Map[K, V]] // error here
            case _: JsUndefined => throw new Exception("Error")
        }
    }
```

> No Json deserializer found for type Map[K,V]. Try to implement an
>   implicit Reads or Format for this type. not enough arguments for
>   method as: (implicit fjs: play.api.libs.json.Reads[Map[K,V]])Map[K,V].
>   Unspecified value parameter fjs.

This function works when I define specific type for Map (ex: v.as[ Map[String, Int]], but not in generic. How should I do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point you will have to have a specific `K` and `V`. At that point you will need the implicit readers in (implicit) scope, until then, you can just implicitly pass them:

```
def getMap[K, V](js: JsValue, key: String)(implicit reads: Reads[Map[K,V]]): Map[K, V] = {
        js \ key match {
            case JsDefined(v) => v.as[Map[K, V]] // error here
            case _: JsUndefined => throw new Exception("Error")
        }
    }
```

I am not sure why you would set it up this way though. Why not do either

`(js \ key).as[Map[K,V]]`
if you want it to throw an error or
`(js \ key).asOpt[Map[K,V]]`
if an Option is ok as well. Or, also possible
`(js \ key).validate[Map[K,V]]`

Comment: Thanks, you saved me :)